# autocomplete return a userid display user text

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Ive been playing with ajax autocomplete and have so far compiled the below

im not quite sure how to do this, but i want autocomplete to show usernames but either have the userid stored or set a hiddenfield to the userid of the user selected. im not sure how to do this though..

oh also, is there a please wait searching addon or something that i can add to let users know its getting the usernames? (its quite slow at the moment!)

Thanks guys

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    dsData.tblUsersDataTable dtUsers = new dsData.tblUsersDataTable();
    dsDataTableAdapters.tblUsersTableAdapter taUsers = new dsDataTableAdapters.tblUsersTableAdapter();
    taUsers.Fill(dtUsers);

    var varUsers = (from d in dtUsers.AsEnumerable() where d.Username.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select d);
    List<string> lstUsers =new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in varUsers)
    {
        lstUsers.Add(dr["Username"].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQueryUI's autocomplete: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
or the autocomplete from the ajaxtoolkit: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx